# Enabling ftp utils on php7 apache container

Tags: php, docker

I am extending the oficial php:apache container https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

```
FROM php:apache
```

This is installing me php7 but is not installing the ftp utils. When I try to use ftp_connect through my php shell it gives me:

```
Warning: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ftp_connect() in php shell code:1
```

I have no idea how to enable the ftp utils. Do I have to install a new package or modify the php.ini? I saw I can enable --with-ftp or --enable-ftp when manually installing php but in this case is being installed through the container.

Comment: Look for "How to install more PHP extensions" on this page: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/, I would say it's something like this `FROM php:apache
RUN docker-php-ext-enable ftp`

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be installed through `docker-php-ext-install ftp`